# How to find/command/sql query to find max number of connections available in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

We are using PostgreSQL. Is there any command to know, what is the maximum number of connections possible? And how many are currently used? And how many additional connections can be made?

Is there any command or SQL query to run and check all this?

Answer (score 1):

smth like should work:

```
t=# select current_setting('max_connections')::int - count(1) from pg_stat_activity;
 ?column?
----------
       93
(1 row)
```

where `current_setting('max_connections')` is allowed maximum, and `pg_stat_activity` knows how many connection and of what type( column `state`)  you have

Answer (score 0):

You can check [max_connections](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/runtime-config-connection.html):

```
postgres=# show max_connections;
```

Output:

```
 max_connections 
-----------------
 30
(1 row)
```

Comment: @gofr1 It answers the first of the two questions, in the most simple way. This could help future readers.

Comment: Sorry, I guess you are right. I add some info to your answer, hope it is useful. :)

Comment: Okay, Thanks for adding the link.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT current_setting('max_connections')::bigint,
       current_setting('superuser_reserved_connections')::bigint,
       count(*) AS current_connections
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE datid IS NOT NULL;
```

The number of available connections is the first entry minus the other two.